# EntityType select return integer instead of object

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Here is part of the form for city

```
->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
          'class'             => 'CFCWalesUserBundle:Zone',
          'query_builder'     => function(EntityRepository $er) {
               return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->where('c.country = :country')
                    ->setParameter('country', $this->country)
                    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
          },
          'choice_label'      => 'name',
          'empty_data'        => null,
          'attr'              => array(
                 'class'     => 'form-control'
               )
     ))
```

Here's the zone's part in User entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="integer")
     */
     private $city;
```

When an option is selected from the city dropdown, I got this error after form submission:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class CFCWales\UserBundle\Entity\Zone could not be converted to string
```

I want $city to store integer value instead of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the __toString () method in the Zone entity class  order to define the value of the combobox field.

Hope this help